# How Can I exist Queries When the User refresh the browser in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

When refresh the Browser, inactive state queries have gone.
How Can I maintain queries When I refresh the Browser?
and also, I want to maintain userData when the pages go out

code like this.. (with zustand, react-query)

```
const {userId} = useParams();
const userData = useStore((state) => state.userData);
const {isLoading, data} = useQuery('user', () => getUser(userId), {
        onSuccess: (res) => {
            useStore.setState({userData: res.data});
        },
        onError: (err) => errorMsg(err),
    });
```

getUser func

```
export const getUser = (userId)=>{
  if(!userId) return;
  
  return axios.get(`${API.user(userId)}`};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Query provides **experimental** (as of June 2022) support for storing data in Local Storage:

```
import { persistQueryClient } from 'react-query/persistQueryClient-experimental'
import { createWebStoragePersistor } from 'react-query/createWebStoragePersistor-experimental'

// probably also supports session storage as the API is the same
const localStoragePersistor = createWebStoragePersistor({storage: window.localStorage})

// the queryClient you pass to QueryClientProvider
persistQueryClient({
  queryClient, 
  persistor: localStoragePersistor,
})
```

Source: https://react-query.tanstack.com/plugins/persistQueryClient